# Why was Dirk Pitt's background changed to the Navy for Sahara?

Tags: character, sahara

In the 2005 adventure film "Sahara", treasure hunter Dirk Pitt and his best friend Al Giordino are said to be former Navy SEALS who joined NUMA after leaving the Navy. From what I've read, though, the book version of the characters served as US Air Force commandoes, with Dirk being an accomplished pilot and restorer of old planes. Seems like a rather odd change.

**Has anyone involved with the production of Sahara commented on why Pitt's military experience was changed to the US Navy for the film?**

Comment: Probably to avoid confusing the audience...and not for the first time. [He graduated from the United States Air Force Academy, and attained the rank of major  (this was changed to the U.S. Naval Academy in the film versions of Raise the Titanic and Sahara)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Pitt)